# How does =~ behave in matching?

Tags: regex, perl

I am confused in the `=~` operator. It seems that it returns a value that is true/false of a match. But when applied using a `g` it returns the actual matches.
Example:

```
 ~
$ perl -e '  
my $var = "03824531449411615213441829503544272752010217443235";  
my @zips = $var =~ /\d{5}/g;  
print join "--", @zips;  
'
03824--53144--94116--15213--44182--95035--44272--75201--02174--43235  

$ perl -e '  
my $var = "03824531449411615213441829503544272752010217443235";  
my @zips = $var =~ /\d{5}/;  
print join "--", @zips;  
'  
1  

$ perl -e '  
my $var = "03824531449411615213441829503544272752010217443235";  
my $zips = $var =~ /\d{5}/;  
print join "--", $zips;  
'  
1
```

So how does this work? Why does it return true/false in non-g mode?Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$var =~ /(\d{5})/;` also returns match in list context, it's only that `/g` does grouping regardless of `()` braces.

Comment: This does not print anything: `$ perl -e '
my $var = "03824531449411615213441829503544272752010217443235";
my $zips = $var =~ /(\d{5})/;
print join "--", $zips;
'
1`

Comment: @Jim you need list context, either by using array `my @arr = ..`, or `my ($zips) = ..`

Comment: Why do I need a list context?If I don't apply a `g` it will match only once.So it would be scalar context, single string right?

Comment: @Jim context depends on left part of assignment, not on `/g` switch (which only repeats match as much as possible)

Comment: So only on a list context the `=~` returns the actual matches?

Answer (score 8):

[`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) already given a pretty clear explanation for this, so I will just copy & paste related part of it:

For `=~` operator:

> Binary "=~" binds a scalar expression to a pattern match. ... When used in scalar context, the return value generally indicates the success of the operation. ... Behavior in list context depends on the particular operator. See [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) for details and `perlretut` for examples using these operators.

For `m//` operator:

> Searches a string for a pattern match, and in scalar context returns true if it succeeds, false if it fails.

For `m//` without `/g` modifier in list context:

> If the `/g` option is not used, `m//` in list context returns a list consisting of the subexpressions matched by the parentheses in the pattern, that is, (`$1`, `$2`, `$3` ...). When there are no parentheses in the pattern, the return value is the list `(1)` for success. With or without parentheses, an empty list is returned upon failure.

For `m//` with `/g` modifier in list context:

> The `/g` modifier specifies global pattern matching--that is, matching as many times as possible within the string. How it behaves depends on the context. In list context, it returns a list of the substrings matched by any capturing parentheses in the regular expression. If there are no parentheses, it returns a list of all the matched strings, as if there were parentheses around the whole pattern.
>
> In scalar context, each execution of `m//g` finds the next match, returning true if it matches, and false if there is no further match.

---

Context of expressions in OP:

1. `@zips = $var =~ /\d{5}/g;`

   `m//g` in list context;
2. `@zips = $var =~ /\d{5}/;`

   `m//` in list context;
3. `$zips = $var =~ /\d{5}/;`

   `m//` in scalar context.